# Design pattern to integrate with many libraries offering the same thing

Tags: design-patterns

I'm writting a card simulator that could make use of a number of libraries, each library has different pros and cons.  I would like to be able to swap between libraries depending on the nature of the simulation. The libraries have similair concepts(e.g. they all know about a card) which allows me to write mostly a single structure of code for my simulation and swap in the various libaries.  My problem is that the entities in the libraries differ slightly and obivously the only common ancestor across the two libraries is object.  Is there a standard approach to this problem?  At the moment I'm thinking of some kind of abstract factory depending on the library I'm using and just live with the fact that some methods will have Object as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Adapter pattern is a common solution in this situation - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern .